# Contextual Links on Comments

Tags: comments, navigation

I would like the user to be able to edit or delete comments from contextual links.  From an example module I've replaced `$items['node/%node/example-action']` with `$items['comment/%comment/edit']` But I've had no joy. Here's the code for the example module.

```
function comment_contextual_links_menu() {

$items['comment/%comment/example-action'] = array(
 'title' => 'Example action',
 'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
 'page arguments' => array('comment_contextual_links_node_action_form', 1),
 'access callback' => TRUE,
 'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
 'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,   
  'weight' => 80, ); 

$items['examples/contextual-links/%comment_contextual_links_object'] = array(
 'title' => 'Contextual links example object',
 'page callback' => 'comment_contextual_links_object_page',
 'page arguments' => array(2),
 'access callback' => TRUE,);

$items['examples/contextual-links/%comment_contextual_links_object/view'] = array(
 'title' => 'View',
 'type' => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK,
 'weight' => -10,  );

$items['examples/contextual-links/%comment_contextual_links_object/edit'] = array(
 'title' => 'Edit object',
 'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
 'page arguments' => array('comment_contextual_links_object_edit_form', 2),
 'access callback' => TRUE,
 'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
 'context' => MENU_CONTEXT_PAGE | MENU_CONTEXT_INLINE,  );

$items['examples/contextual-links'] = array(
 'title' => 'Contextual Links Example',
 'page callback' => 'contextual_links_overview_page',
 'access callback' => TRUE,  );

return $items;
exit('yes');
}
```

Comment: Standard checks: Are you sure the module is enabled? Did you clear cache? Are you sure the comment_contextual_links_menu function is called? (E.g. just add `exit('yes');` and clear cache to check :-))

Comment: Yes module is enabled. Cache fully cleared. Added  - exit('yes'); - to end of code before closing bracket and after - return  $items; - (edited to code above) Cleared cache again. No contextual links in comments.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. What if you add the `exit('yes');` right before the `return;` statement? If your function is called correctly, a cache-clear should then exit early, displaying "yes" on your screen. If you don't see it, and your page loads as usual, your code is not called, so you should check if your menu hook is named correctly (is this code in `comment_contextual_links.module`?)

Comment: Yes. the exit ("yes"); command has indeed resulted in a "yes" on my screen. So we know that the code is being called.

Comment: Well, then at least we know that the problem must be in the menu items' definitions. I hope somebody knows the answer.